# what does somebody's "release date" mean?

Tags: idioms

I am reading a book "Pro git", in the preface, the author says:

> I would like to dedicate this, my first print book, to my little girl, Josephine,  whose release date was nearly the same as this book’s.

So what does "Josephine's release date" mean? birthday? wedding day? or other meaning?

Comment: Is the release date of your software the date it gets married or the date it is birthed from your development into the world?

Comment: @MattЭллен: Of course the author is joking, but I am wondering what this stylistic device is called - using a word which means the same thing but in a different context?

Comment: @ArmenԾիրունյան [metaphor](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/metaphor?q=metaphor)

Comment: @MattЭллен: I feel stupid :)

Comment: No need to feel stupid. Everyone has times like that :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about literary interpretation.

Comment: The author's daughter apparently went bad at an early age.  (The most common use of *release date* when applied to people is to specify prison release dates.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Josephine's release date" means when she was born. The author is joking that his first print book was released on almost the same day his daughter was born.

Answer (score 1):

I think "release date" actually refers to the book and is a metaphor for the girls birthday.